# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.keras' in Django

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras

I am working opencv and tensorflow with django but I got stucked in this error and I'm not able not fix it.
Here are the libraries that I have imported

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, ZeroPadding2D, Activation, Input, concatenate
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
from keras.layers.core import Lambda, Flatten, Dense
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

with info in question, looks like you need to use tensorflow in an async process like celery. works with tensorflow 2.0,  keras 2.3.1 and Django 2.1.12

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue before. I suggest you use Django **2.2** or **3.0.5** to fix your problem.